# Need to make SDL/OpenGL window size larger than screen size

Tags: opengl, window, screen, sdl, sdl-2

I need to take snapshots of 3D models from different angles.
For this I am using **SDL** and **OpenGL**.
But when I try to make the **window size larger than the screen size**, it **resizes down** to fit in, which is not what I want.

Is there any **proper or hacky way** to do so?

Comment: You may use FBO greater (max size could be query) than screen if It's for offscreen rendering.

Comment: This is what I am doing using shadow mapping....(Pardon, I don't know OpenGL well). Although understood partially, but still cant figure out, where is my error. Please help.  Link to pastebin code: [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/AfgkgydJ)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a framebuffer object with an appropriately sized renderbuffer target. If the maximum supported renderbuffer size doesn't suffice your needs, implement tiled rendering.

**Do not use on-screen windows** to create renderings which you require to be "perfect" and in pristine conditions. The on-screen framebuffer is unreliable, in the sense, that its contents may get clobbered at any time by the operating system, if the need arises.

Also since the window framebuffer is, well actually just a real window into a larger, single screen framebuffer, you'll have a hard time making it bigger than the screen size.

Comment: Agreed. If you don't need to interact, or require the highest performance, render offscreen. If you still need to see your output on the screen e.g. to get your angle right for your snapshot, copy it from your FBO and scale it down to the window. Then take your snapshot from the FBO which is higher resolution. I think most high end implementations support at least 4kx4k rendering.

Comment: This is what I am doing using shadow mapping....(Pardon, I don't know OpenGL well). Although understood partially, but still cant figure out, where is my error. Please help.  Link to pastebin code: [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/AfgkgydJ)

Comment: @SMH: Line 63 makes no sense. You already rendered the shadow map directly to the texture. No need to copy anything. And in the subsequent rendering from the camera's vantage point you still have the shadow map framebuffer bound. You must bind another framebuffer first (either the on-screen default 0, or the render-to-renderbuffer `fbo[1]`) and again no need to copy anything to the destination buffers. But eventually you'll have to use glReadPixels to retrieve the generated image.

Comment: @datenwolf: okay! i will check that. **But my main point is that the final rendering is still resized down on a big size image(larger than the screen size which I require.)** i.e. upper part of the image is un-rendered. I want it to render on a off-screen surface larger than the screen size. **Even after using FBOs the rendering is same resized in an ugly aspect ratio.** (N.B. I am using SDL2 and OpenGL 3.1)

Comment: @SMH: You must call glViewport after binding a framebuffer with offset and size matching the target renderbuffer. This is missing from your code as well.

Comment: @datenwolf: thanks! now the aspect ratio, scale and position are correct. But, the rendering gets cropped off beyond the size of the screen, in my case at the top.

Comment: @SMH: Then you're likely not rendering to a FBO but the on-screen framebuffer. Do you have your complete code somewhere?

Comment: @datenwolf: **Thanks a lot to all of you!** I overlooked a silly mistake which I had made later. i.e. instead of `glGenFramebuffers(2, fbo);` , I mistyped to  `glGenFramebuffers(1, fbo);` Now, its working perfectly. :)